# Appending CHAR to STR within a for-loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, append

I have made a simple C++ console calculator which does what it's supposed to. After it completes a calculation, it asks the user if he/she wants to make another one. If yes, the loop repeats until the user says no; if no the app shows "CLOSING" and closes after 2 seconds.

Instead of the static "CLOSING" message, I want the program to show "CLOSING", wait half second show "CLOSING.", another half "CLOSING..", another "CLOSING..." , and close through exit(-1), 
you get the idea...

I have accomplished this (with a for-loop) BUT each cout is on a different line.
e.g.

CLOSING.

CLOSING..

CLOSING...

I want it to be a static "CLOSING" but '.' gets appended three times.

**Here's the code:**

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3 ; a++)
        {
            Closing += ".";
            std::cout<<Closing<<std::endl;
            Sleep(500);
```

*sClosing is a string I defined as "CLOSING" above main().

So to repeat my question: **Is there any way to have one line, with one "CLOSING" and only the '.' gets appended (3 times)?**

*I am sorry if this is obvious; I am new to C++ but not to programming, so if you would please explain the goal/function of something like say '\f'.

This is also my first post on StackOverflow so if something was unclear or wrong (in terms of formatting etc. please help a noob out ;-) *

Comment: Just a small remark: even though some animation while closing looks cool at first, in fact it becomes a nuisance pretty soon.  But you will find out soon enough and then you can remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most consoles, using the carriage return character (`'\r'`) will do exactly this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::cout << "Closing";
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        std::cout << '.';
    }
    std::cout << '\r';
    Sleep(500);
}
```

This is also extremely useful if you have a program where instead of just appending a period, you want it to change the message periodically.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::cout << "Closing";
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        std::cout << '.';
    }
    std::cout << '\r';
    Sleep(500);
}
std::cout << "Now Closed!" << '\n';
```

Your other option is to find a library that lets you dynamically program the console, but that might overcomplicate what looks like a relatively simple program.

Comment: I never thought using a for loop inside a for loop! Thanks so much!

Comment: Just one question though, what does the \r do exactly? I can see clears the line, but if there was an open line (\n) would it remove that, or could it remove multiple lines?

Comment: @madcode `\r` returns the cursor to the beginning of the line like `\n` does, but unlike `\n`, it doesn't *also* jump to the next line. So you can write whatever you want (as long as it fits in the width of a single line in your console), follow it with a `\r`, and then anything you write will "overwrite" the characters you already wrote on that line. If you then use a `\n`, you'll jump to the next line, and the characters on the previous line won't be "overwritable" anymore (unless you're using dynamic console programming, which is beyond the scope of this answer).

Comment: @madcode Incidentally, `\r` doesn't clear the line on its own. If you were to write something like `std::cout << "My line of data\rHey\r";` The resulting text would be `Heyline of data`. If you need to blank the line, write out enough space characters to fill the width of the console.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I will definitely use this awesome site again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `std::endl` which adds a newline.

```
std::cout << "CLOSING";
for (int a = 0; a < 3 ; a++)
{
    Sleep(500);
    std::cout << ".";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Nope. This way you'll get ``CLOSING CLOSING.CLOSING..``